# Django Models ManyToMany and Foreign Key

Tags: python, database, django, models, relationships

Trying to get a better handle on how django database relationships are handled.
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Considering the following example models:

```
class Things(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Stuff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    information = models.ManyToManyField('Information')
    things = models.ForeignKey('Things')

class Information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stuff = models.ForeignKey('Stuff')
```

An error results from `syncdb`: `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'ForeignKey'`. The error results if I include *both* the `ManyToManyField` and the `Foreign Key` fields in the `Stuff` model.

Is there a way that I can make both of these relationships exist? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Isn't there conflict. In _Stuff_ you have _ManyToMany_ with _Information_, but in _ManyToOne_ with _Stuff_ in _Information_.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your code sample whether the relationship between Information and Stuff is supposed to be one-to-many or many-to-many.

Comment: The idea is that `Stuff` can have multiple `information`, but that `Information` references one type of `Stuff`. So a ManyToMany from `Stuff` to `Information`, and a ForeignKey from `Information` to `Stuff`. It works great in my head, but not in Django. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know how many `information` are linked to each `stuff`, django will provide a default [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) that will allow you to go backwards; for this you don't need a foreign key in `stuff`.

```
class Things(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Stuff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    information = models.ManyToManyField('Information')
    things = models.ForeignKey('Things')

class Information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

This model will allow you to do queries like:

- "What is the `information` for `stuff` `X` ?"
- "For `stuff` `Y`, what `information` is linked?"
- "Find me all `stuff` and `information` for `thing` `Z`"

In addition it will allow you have multiple `information` for each `stuff` and multiple `stuff` for each `thing`.

Writing down these questions at the start will help you develop accurate models without unnecessary links/relations in your database.

Answer (score 0):

My version of django gives a bit more information:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
foo.stuff: Reverse query name for m2m field 'information' clashes with field 'Information.stuff'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'information'.
foo.information: Reverse query name for field 'stuff' clashes with m2m field 'Stuff.information'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'stuff'.
```

Which is probably enough to get you going.  Define a `related_name` for both the `ManyToManyField` relationship and the `ForeignKey` relationship from Information to Stuff...

```
information = models.ManyToManyField('Information', related_name='stuff_many_set')
stuff = models.ForeignKey('Stuff', related_name = 'info_set')
```

then `syncdb` will be happy.  Of course, you should be sure that you need both the relationships.  With the generic entity names here it looks like there may be some confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Adding a 'related_name' argument to the models has not solved the issue, however. Python still says: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'ForeignKey', only if I have both a Foreign Key and a ManyToManyField on the Stuff model.

Comment: What are you using as the `related_names` parameters? You may be colliding with one of values that django generates. Also: what version of django are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you would get an error like this:

```
$python manage.py syncdb
Error: One or more models did not validate:
t.stuff: Reverse query name for m2m field 'information' clashes with field  'Information.stuff'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'information'.
t.information: Reverse query name for field 'stuff' clashes with m2m field 'Stuff.information'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'stuff'.
```

why? simple you have two tables referencing each other, the problem here is that when reverse look ups are applied django will generate the same name, creating a clash.

To fix this issue, like the error states, you need to add `related_name` this way django knows how to distinguish the different reverse calls.

```
from django.db import models

class Things(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Stuff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    information = models.ManyToManyField('Information', related_name = 'information_information')
    things = models.ForeignKey('Things')

class Information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stuff = models.ForeignKey('Stuff', related_name = 'information_stuff')
```

Sorry Im not very creative with the names, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Adding a 'related_name' argument to the models has not solved the issue, however. Python still says: `'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'ForeignKey'`, only if I have *both* a Foreign Key and a ManyToManyField on the Stuff model.

Comment: @NickB you must be doing something else cause the example I posted works just fine, you must be testing your own code which may have another issue.